# An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application'] > Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'

Tags: android

i´m trying to make an app with Android Studio, but it shows me this error, and i cand find whats´s wrong...

ERROR: * Where:
Build file 'D:\PROYECTO OVO\�ltimo Avance - Angelo Canales\ProyectoOVO\ProyectoOVO\app\build.gradle' line: 2

- What went wrong:
  An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
> Your project path contains non-ASCII characters. This will most likely cause the build to fail on Windows. Please move your project to a different directory. See http://b.android.com/95744 for details. This warning can be disabled by adding the line 'android.overridePathCheck=true' to gradle.properties file in the project directory.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.

BUILD FAILED in 596ms

this is my file build.gradle(Module:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.proyectoovo"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    namespace 'com.example.proyectoovo'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'nl.joery.animatedbottombar:library:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.6'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.6'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.9.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
    implementation 'com.github.davidmigloz:multi-state-switch:2.0.1'
    implementation("io.github.vicmikhailau:MaskedEditText:4.0.7")
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.3.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.2')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx:23.4.0'
    implementation("com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.3.3")
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:8.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx:20.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.6.2"
    implementation 'com.github.harry1453:android-bluetooth-serial:v1.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.12'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:22.3.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:latest.release'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:latest.release'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.5.0'

    implementation 'com.arthenica:mobile-ffmpeg-full-gpl:4.4.LTS'

}
```

i try to change some lines like targetSdk 33